# Sinal de perigo em uma var em C

Tags: c

O programa e a recursividade estão corretas, mas mesmo assim, ocorre um sinal perigo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ant_suc (int num){
    int ant = num - 1;
    int suc = num + 1;

    return printf("O numero antecessor a %d eh %d e seu sucessor eh %d", num, ant, suc);
}

int main(void){
    int num;
    printf("Informe um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    ant_suc(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando o printf como retorno da função ant_suc, que foi definida como tipo void e não espera retorno de algum tipo.

Declarando a função ant_suc da forma abaixo deve resolver o problema de warning, além de ser a maneira correta de tratar função do tipo void:

```
void ant_suc (int num){
    int ant = num - 1;
    int suc = num + 1;
    printf("O numero antecessor a %d eh %d e seu sucessor eh %d", num, ant, suc);
    return;
 }
```

Comment: Percebi agora, obrigada.